# MySQL Sync on System Start

Tags: mysql, rsync

Can anyone think of a good way to sync a mysql database with another mysql database before the server starts up? I thought maybe i could rsync the directories in rc.d, but that seems dicey.   The server's running on FreeBSD.

Thanks.

For clarification:

Alright.  I am setting up mysql as a session store for a php web application.  I have written a class that overrides php's session methods with methods that offer benefits important to our web app.  In the interest of the maximum speed, the main mysql server is storing its data in a tmpfs partition.  It replicates to a server with an SSD.

In the event of a failure, my session management class will automatically roll over to the slave, but when the master reboots, and the mysql service starts, session requests will be redirected at it, but there will be no data present.  Ergo, I need to get the data from the slave during the boot sequence of the master.

Comment: Have you ever think about using master-slave replication?

Comment: When you say "*before the server starts up*", one presumes you're referring to the MySQL dæmon rather than the machine on which it's running - but by that are you referring to the receiving server, the sending server, or both?  Can you provide more information on your reasons for requiring the databases to be synchronised *prior* to the server being started?

Comment: @mserioli: That would only synchronise *after* both servers have started, no?

Comment: Replication enables data from one MySQL database server (the master) to be replicated to one or more MySQL database servers (the slaves). Replication is asynchronous - slaves need not be connected permanently to receive updates from the master. This means that updates can occur over long-distance connections and even over temporary or intermittent connections such as a dial-up service. Depending on the configuration, you can replicate all databases, selected databases, or even selected tables within a database.. From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

Comment: Replication isn't really an option.  What I need is to sync a server that is restarting with another server during it's boot sequence.  By sync, I mean bring the booting server up to date with the other.  The scenario is complicated, but just take this as necessity.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what is "complicated" about your scenario, as it will almost certainly shape what is the most appropriate solution.

Comment: If one server is accepting changes, you can never get them _in sync_ before the other one starts, as _in sync_ is a constantly moving target. Just setting up replication _but only accepting queries when the seconds behind master reaches 0_ is a valid option.

Comment: Server doesn't have to be perfectly in sync, I just don't want my users to have to relog.

Comment: Well, then just `xtrabackup` & copy over as fast as possible. Logins / session changes between making the backup & starting the new server will be lost.

Comment: All of the answers are fantastic, and I thank you guys for the inspiration.  XtraBackup looks like exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both mysql servers are down: `rsync`-ing the `datadir` (which I assume is *not* in `rc.d`, as that would be weird?) before staring them both is not a problem, and works fine as long as the version of `mysql` on the new server is higher or equal (you may need to run `mysql_upgrade` on a higher version).

If the first is running, you preferable want a master-slave scenario, starting from a hotcopy. With Percona's [`Xtrabackup`](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtrabackup) you can back up a live database including InnoDB table with the minimal amount of locking possible (but some locking still occurs!), you copy that datadir to the new server. Now, it is as 'in sync' as you can get it, but the 1st server is still working, so data is changing constantly. To get it in sync with those changes again [set it up as a slave](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/howtos/setting_up_replication.html) at the point stored in the `xtrabackup_binlog_info` file.

Comment: D'ohh you beat me by 30 seconds!

Comment: Hah, score! :P Loved SQL Antipatterns BTW :)

Comment: I too, got much use from SQL antipatterns. I didn't even notice your name.  Now I feel like a celebrity since you commented on my question. And when I said in rc.d I meant inside a shell script run at boot located in rc.d.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the mysqld daemon is shut down, you can rsync a data directory to another location. Both the origin and destination servers should have their mysql daemons shut down.

It is **not safe** to rsync the data directory of a running mysqld instance, nor to copy it to a running mysqld instance. This is because at any time, part of the data could still be in memory, not yet written to disk. If you use only rsync to copy it, you'll get an incomplete database and pretty much guarantee to corrupt it.

Another option is to use Percona XtraBackup, which performs a quick, online, physical copy of data. It includes a mode to send its output over a network so you can use it to initialize a new server immediately.

See http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/howtos/recipes_ibkx_stream.html for examples of doing a streaming backup.

Comment: The instance needing to be copied from has to remain running.  The data lost during the sync isn't a terrible concern though, as it's just session variables.